# Decrypting PCLCrypto using php

Tags: php, xamarin, encryption

I am using PCLCrypto in xamarin to encrypt data before sending it to an API file on the server. The API is coded using PHP. I am struggling to code a deycryption code equivlant to this one

```
public static string DecryptAes(string data, byte[] salt)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] key = CreateDerivedKey(SYMMETRICKEY, salt);

        ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aes = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        ICryptographicKey symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
        var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        var bytes = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(symetricKey, encryptedBytes);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    #endregion
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I doesn't seem like PHP supports PCLCrypto. You may use other algorythms like SHA-512 instead.

Comment: @chade_ SHA-512 is a hashing algorithm, he is using AES here...

Comment: @chade_ thanks please if you have any links or direction to help me i would appreciate it

Comment: @Cheesebaron any suggestions please

Comment: openssl_decrypt is probably what you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php

Answer (score 1):

PCLCrypto use algorithm MD5 and can be use in PHP

```
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {  
    Debug.WriteLine(ByteArrayToHex((GetHash("a")))); 
}

public static byte[] GetHash(string data) {
    IHashAlgorithmProvider algoProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Md5);
    byte[] dataTB = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    return algoProv.HashData(dataTB); 
}

//Convert hash to hex 
private static string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] hash) {
    var hex = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in hash)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

    return hex.ToString(); 
}
```